# Why in UCM Clearcase component which are configured in Child stream being removed when rebase is done?

Tags: clearcase-ucm

We have created new UCM project with 4 components.

Assume Component A, Component B, Component C and Component D.

While we created the child stream that component is added in configuration tab.

One of the person has done some rebase activity after that we were unable to see the contents of the component D.

When analyzed we found that the "component D" is removed from child stream configuration while it remains in integration stream configuration.

How it is getting automatically removed? We are forced to add this to configuration again and again. It is annoyiong . Is there any way to permanently solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a result of:

- component dependency (where D wouldn't be listed as a dependent component of another component)
- recommended baselines (A, B C baselines are recommended, D  is not) in the parent stream: a rebase uses what is recommended by default.

For instance, the [`cleartool rebase` man page](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm) does include:

> Depending on whether `-recommended` or `-baseline` is used, the result of rebasing to a composite baseline may be different.

For example, the foundation baseline for a development stream is **composite baseline** `X1`, which selects member baselines `A1`, `B1` and `C1`.

> New baselines `A2` and `A3` are created in the parent stream and picked up by the development stream through rebase operations. Now the foundation baselines for the development stream are X1 and `A3`. (`A3` now overrides the `A1` that is a member of composite baseline `X1`.)

```
X1
  A2
  B1
  C1
A3 (override)
```

> Then, in the parent stream, a **new composite baseline**, `X2`, is made and recommended.
>
> This baseline selects `A2`, `B2`, and `C2`.
>
> Now, when you `rebase -recommended`, **`A3` is removed from the foundation of the development stream**.

```
X2
  A2
  B2
  C2
```

> The new foundation baselines for the development stream are `X2` and its members.
>
> However, if you rebase to `X2` using the `-baseline` option, `A3` is not removed from the foundation, and the new foundation baselines for the development stream are `X2` and `A3`.

```
X2
  A2
  B2
  C2
A3 (overrides A2)
```